# How can I solve dependency issue with my react nav

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

So I'm a newbie to reactnative, trying to learn to develop apps. I was trying to learn how to use React Navigation so I installed it and dependancies but then when I try to use it I'm getting a few errors. The first appears in cmd after running npm start:

```
Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version:
 - react-native-screens - expected version range: 2.0.0-alpha.12 - actual version installed: ^2.0.0-alpha.12
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]
```

And then when I launch the app in Android sim I get this:

```
Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/drawer" from "App.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, Image, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'native-base';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Search from './src/search';
import Landing from './src/landing';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack'
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs'
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs'


var myBackground = require('./assets/icons/landing.jpg');
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const MaterialBottomTabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const MaterialTopTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();


export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {

  }

  createHomeStack = () =>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen  name="Feed"/>
  </Stack.Navigator>

  createTopTabs = () =>
  {
    return <MaterialTopTabs.Navigator>
      <MaterialTopTabs.Screen name="Tab1" Component={Landing}/>
    </MaterialTopTabs.Navigator>
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" Component="Landing"/>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Search" Component="Search"/>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home"/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 50 : 0
  },
});
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting these errors? I did a fresh install of React Nav right before starting this.
Thanks in advance!

Package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.8",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Attach your package.json code here

Comment: too long for comment so i added it in a edit

Comment: as in your package.json you haven't install drawer navigation to your project. Thats why

Answer (score 1):

So in your case as your pacakge.json shows, you haven't installed the packages which are used to drawer and stack. After solving drawer issue you will get stack issue.. Follow these steps top reproduce your problem

More information about [React Navigation Version 5.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)

**Install drawer package using this :**

```
npm i -s @react-navigation/drawer
```

**Install navigation stack using this :**

```
npm i -s @react-navigation/stack
```

**Install material bottom tabs using this :**

```
npm i -s @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs
```

**Install Material top tabs using this :**

```
npm i -s @react-navigation/material-top-tabs
```

- **You should follow all the above steps to solve issues with your project**

After installing all the above dependencies you need to clean and rebuild your project and uninstall the previous version from the emulator and run again

**[About Tab Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation)**

**[About Drawer Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation)**

Comment: I just tried that but after running those lines when I run npm start i got an error saying react-native is not installed, so I tried running npm install react-native and then tried rerunning and then I got this error: 

warn Package native-base has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'native-base\package.json'
Require stack: